# Android Studio Multiple Language not change the Language on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to change the Language of my Application it is working fine in all Activity but it doesn't change the Language in the MainActivity.
So I can select in the Settings French as Language it changes the Language in SettingsActivity, Activity 2 but not in the MainActivity.
How can I solve this Problem?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


      
public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    loadLocale();
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    Button changeLang = findViewById(R.id.changeMyLang);
    changeLang.setOnClickListener (view -> showChangeLanguageDialog());
}

private void showChangeLanguageDialog() {
    final String[] listItems = {"French", "English"};
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
    mBuilder.setTitle("Choose Language...");
    mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (i==0){
                setLocale("fr");
                recreate();
            }
            else if (i==1){
                setLocale("en");
                recreate();
            }

            dialogInterface.dismiss();

        }
    });

    AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();

    mDialog.show();
}

private void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("My_Lang", lang);
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadLocale(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString("My_Lang", "");
    setLocale(language);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide other activities code also recreate method implementation